# Using bulma accordions, out of two accordions , how to display the later accordion , on click of a button inside the former accordion?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, accordion, buttonclick, bulma

I am using bulma and vuejs, i want to have three bulma accordions. Namely, Accordion1 and Accordion2, Accordion3. I am able to make the three accordions simultaneously. But now i would like to display Accordion1 at first and have a Button inside it, which on click accordion1 should close and accordion2 should be displayed automatically, similarly for accordion2 i want to have a button inside , which onClick closes accordion2 and displays accordion3. I do not want to hide the preceding accordion. So that when the user reaches accordion3 , all the accordions are visible. how can i achieve this?

---

```
<BulmaAccordion>
              <BulmaAccordionItem>
                <h1 slot="title">Accordion1</h1>
                <div slot="content">
                  <div class="field">
                   <button></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </BulmaAccordionItem>
            </BulmaAccordion>

<BulmaAccordion>
              <BulmaAccordionItem>
                <h1 slot="title">Accordion2</h1>
                <div slot="content">
                  <div class="field">
                   <button></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </BulmaAccordionItem>
            </BulmaAccordion>

<BulmaAccordion>
              <BulmaAccordionItem>
                <h1 slot="title">Accordion3</h1>
                <div slot="content">
                  <div class="field">
                   <button></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </BulmaAccordionItem>
            </BulmaAccordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bulma + Vue, i would suggest `Buefy` with its `Collapse with Accordion effect` (doc link [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/collapse/#accordion-effect)). Basically you just need to use `v-for` loop for indexing, and trigger click event per button according index (e.g to open 2nd after click Btn1, make condition open to index 1 (starts from 0 in array), and open 0 and 1 indexes for Btn3 click)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I understood what you are trying to convey, but by any chance is it possible to hide accordion2 from user , unless a button inside accordion1 is clicked? so after the button is clicked it is displayed permanently.

Comment: by default is closed, unless you initialized the index to start with `1` which is 2nd Row in accordion to open. If these helps, green tick/Best Answer would be grateful :) Cheers